# Sorting a list (string) numerically from high to low c#

Tags: c#, sorting

Context: I am designing a leader board and want to have the data displayed from the highest score to the lowest score. The problem being the data contains a string and integers which are imported from a text file. Currently I am able to sort the data numerically however I am using the OrderByDescending function which does not work. E.g 11,4,5,8,23,65 when ordered = 8,65,5,4,23,11 (sorted alphanumerically).
The list contains the data: name(string), difficulty(string) and score(int) and I wish to sort the data in a descending order: E.g 1st = 10, 2nd = 9 etc.

```
List<string> leaderboardList = new List<string>();
StreamReader srUserData = new StreamReader(@"User Leaderboard.txt");
while ((userDataLine = srUserData.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            leaderboardList.Add(userDataLine);
        }

leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x => Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value).ToList();
```

The Regex.Match finds the number in the string. 
Basically the final line is the line that needs amending.
All help welcome, thanks.

Edit: The data should be outputted in the form Name, difficulty, score and sort the data in a descending order with the highest score.

Comment: Is this data you will perform multiple functions with?  Why not parse the data once into a class with individual properties?  That way you can parse the data once, then perform all sorts of functions on the native types (sorting, string manipulation, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value).ToList();
```

To:

```
leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value)).ToList();
```

Just add the [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) really.  A caveat though: If you pass a string that is not a number `Int32.Parse()` will throw an exception.  If this is a possibility that needs to be handled, then you can use [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Ex:

```
int testValue = 0; //This is only used for TryParse()
leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x =>
        Int32.TryParse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value, out testValue)
        ? testValue : 0M).ToList();
```

Tested using the following example list:

```
List<string> leaderboardList = new List<string>();
leaderboardList.Add("Brandon|Easy|9");
leaderboardList.Add("Yoda|Impossible|9001");
leaderboardList.Add("Barney|Easy|-1");
leaderboardList.Add("John|Normal|500");
```

This code works correctly, and the TryParse code was not needed.

Output:

```
Yoda|Impossible|9001
John|Normal|500
Brandon|Easy|9
Barney|Easy|-1
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: The data in leaderboard list includes a name, a difficulty e.g easy and then the number

Comment: @OranPower See the example list I used to test in my edit.  Does that match the data you are inputing?

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly Using TryParse.
I was just wondering what the difference is between the following lines of code as the bottom one doesnt work:
    leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.TryParse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value, out testValue)? testValue : 0M).ToList();
            
    leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value)).ToList();

Comment: @OranPower `TryParse` will not throw an exception if your input is not in the correct format.  Instead it will return false.  Essentially, `Int32.Parse` requires that your input be the string representation of a number.  If it is not a number it throws an exception.  More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @OranPower When you pass in your values, does every user have a score? Or do you sometimes not include the score in the input?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a completely different approach from the others.  Load your string from disk, then parse it into a class you have defined.  For example:

```
public class LeaderboardRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code would look more like this:

```
List<LeaderboardRow> leaderboardList = new List<LeaderboardRow>();
StreamReader srUserData = new StreamReader(@"User Leaderboard.txt");
while ((userDataLine = srUserData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Put logic here that parses your string row into 3 distinct values
    leaderboardList.Add(new LeaderboardRow()
    {
        Score = 0, //put real value here
        Name = string.Empty, //put real value here
        Difficulty = string.Empty //put real value here
    });
}
```

Then any ordering you need to do is a simple LINQ statement:

```
leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

Depending on your scenario/requirements you could store this text as json instead which could speed up and simplify your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could go old school and perform Integer.TryParse or some derivative of such functions. Once you do that you can append them into a list of integers.

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
if (result) {
Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one thing, that is you are not convert Regex value to int. Please check below code, it's works for me.

CODE:

```
List<string> leaderboardList = new List<string>();
leaderboardList.Add("A,A,9");
leaderboardList.Add("B,B,8");
leaderboardList.Add("G,C,65");
leaderboardList.Add("S,B,10");

leaderboardList = leaderboardList.OrderByDescending(x =>Convert.ToInt32((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value)?"0":Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value))).ToList();
foreach (var item in leaderboardList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Online output: [.Net Fiddle Output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hgzbdC)

Comment: Can you share your sample data. That will help to solve this error.

Comment: input: e.g ORAN Arsenal Hard 3

Comment: Then different names followed by football team followed by difficulty then their score

Comment: Please check my [fiddle output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t8YDAn). If your data always has score then it will work.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the score can be empty?

Comment: I've handled the empty score, please check [fiddle output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t8YDAn).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for ordering list of numbers in string or list of string that contains numbers.

[The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

I hope this works for you.